# ASP.Net: Add extra files to be monitored to trigger AppDomain recycle

Tags: .net, asp.net, iis

All of my Asp.Net websites use a separate configuration system, driven by XML files, which is responsible for building an awful lot of the objects used throughout the sites; effectively a series of uber IOC containers might be used to resolve anything from controllers for MVC sites, to data services and configuration objects for back-end code.

The XML builds a bunch of dynamic methods which are then hidden behind a factory interface.  Once loaded and built, those methods will not be rebuilt until the App Domain recycles.

The smallest change in one of the files, then, can have a profound effect on the functionality of the website and thus updates often can be deployed as a simple config change.  The files can appear within the website root and any child folder within it - but not, typically in any of the standard Asp.Net folders (App_LocalResources etc).

But because the files don't use an extension that Asp.Net/IIS recognises as being 'important' (let's say the extension is `.configfoo`), if I change one of them I have to manually ensure an app domain restart on the server by either:

a) Touch the web.config to force an AppDomain restart; or

b) Recompile the binaries

What I would like to do is to somehow tell Asp.Net/IIS to include these files in its monitoring, and treat them as being *as important* as .config files and the .dlls in the bin folder; triggering an app domain restart if any of them change.

### UPDATE in response to Artem's answer

I've tried placing the files in either the `bin\` or in `App_LocalResources`, for example, and indeed the AppDomain is restarted - which is good news, but...  I don't like `bin\` deployment because the only way to get the file updated easily in development is to do a build (unless you manually copy/paste) and it also doesn't fit with the concept of these files being Content - which is what they actually are, and need to be treated as from a deployment perspective.

Equally, the `App_LocalResources` (et al) solution is great, but is not natural from a developer point of view - it's a configuration file and therefore should be able to placed in the same place as other configuration files (there's also the small matter that VS seems not to see my Item Template that I've done if I'm adding to this folder due to its context-sensitive Add New Item dialog).

Finally it doesn't solve the problem of the other freeform folders that a project might have which might contain `.configfoo` files alongside aspx/ascx/master/.config files etc.  Unless I force these folders to all be placed inside one of the Asp.Net folders of course, but nobody expects to find a page inside `App_LocalResources`!

### END Update

Failing this - I do remember seeing a bit of code a couple of years ago where a `FileSystemWatcher` was used, which triggered an `AppDomain.Unload` within the site itself according to its own file-based rules.  I think the preferred method now would be to use `System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.InitiateShutdown`.

This would be my last resort as I'm hesitant to roll my own when I already know that what I want is already being done for some other extensions.

So is it possible to add other dependancy files to those being watched?  Or am I going to have to roll my own?

Any advice, as always, greatly appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the end I rolled my own.

On web application startup I set up a `FileSystemWatcher` monitoring the `AppDomain.BaseDirectory` and all its sub folders with a filter of `*.configfoo`.

I then hooked into the four events that are raised (Created, Renamed, Deleted, Changed) which then calls `System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.InitiateShutDown()` (and then sets a flag to prevent it calling it again, as the FileSystemWatcher will often raise multiple events for one file system action).

Finally set `FileSystemWatcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;` and hey presto.

Answer (score 0):

с) Place config files inside one of the monitored directories, such as App_LocalResources: [monitored for creation, deletion, renaming, ACL changes, changes to the last-write time, and changes to the size](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tmarq/archive/2007/11/02/asp-net-file-change-notifications-exactly-which-files-and-directories-are-monitored.aspx).

Comment: Hi Artem - it's a good solution for a non-complex case; but in this case it won't be workable (I have updated my answer) as I have other folders that also need to be monitored that'll also contain page markup etc.  Interestingly, whilst that article implies that the root virtual directory of the site is monitored just like these others, clearly it is more specific about the kind of changes it's sensitive too; whereas the App_(Local|Global)Resource and Bin folder monitors are sensitive to *any* change.